# Having trouble getting PHP If/Else function to work

Tags: php, if-statement

A simple countdown function, but it is only returning output2, even when the result of $zero is a positive number. That is to say, regardless of the date ('ed') that I put in.

```
function calculate_time($atts){
    
    $ed = $atts['ed'];
    $zero = strtotime($ed);
            $current=strtotime('now');
            $diffference =($zero-$current);
            $days=floor($diffference / (60*60*24));
            $output1 = "$days days left";
            $output2 = "sorry - all gone. But keep checking back. Every so often, something does end up here!";
if ($zero <= 0){
    return $output1;
} else {
    return $output2;
}}
add_shortcode( 'countdown', 'calculate_time' );
```

I tried making sure that $zero was expressed as an integer - which then stopped the function from working.
I experimented and switch the condition from <= to >=. It then gives me a numerical value (a negative integer if before today's date), but not output2.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `$diffference` and not `$zero` there?

Comment: That was worth a try, but still end up with the same result. Thank you, though.

Comment: I take it back. That was the answer. (I forgot to delete the cache on the page before trying the fix.)
Thank you for the other set of eyes. This was driving me batty!